# Javascript two functions on one click

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, load

I'm trying to load two different files in 2 different DIVs. Here is the code I'm using

```
var please_wait = null;
function open_url(url, target) {
    if (!document.getElementById) {
        return false;
    }
    if (please_wait != null) {
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = please_wait;
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        link = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        link = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (link == undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    link.onreadystatechange = function () {
        response(url, target);
    }
    link.open("GET", url, true);
    link.send(null);
}
function response(url, target) {
    if (link.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = (link.status == 200) ? link.responseText : "Ooops!! A broken link! Please contact the webmaster of this website  and give him the following errorcode: " + link.status;
    }
}
function set_loading_message(msg) {
    please_wait = Loding;
}
```

and for call on a link I'm using this code...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="open_url('firstpage.php','containerA');open_url('secondpage.php','containerB')">  Click Here </a>
```

It simply loads the later one in WHATSOEVER case. I've tried a hell different things, made absolutely two different methods, e.g open_url2 but no avail. It loads only one request at one time in a DIV. Any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of extra work by using old school ajax calls.  I think you'd have better luck with jQuery ajax methods.

As for why the latter gets loaded, have you checked firebug or other network tools to see if both files do get loaded?  **If they are both getting loaded, I believe that what's probably happening is the latter is overwriting the first with that .innerHTML function you're using**.  You want to append.  Check out these links, doing it with jQuery would be much easier:

[Making Ajax calls](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[Appending to an element](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using `link` as a global variable. Therefore the second call to `open_url()` is overwriting the value of `link` created from the first.

You should make it local to the `open_url()` function, and pass it to the `response()` function.

```
var please_wait = null;
function open_url(url, target) {

      // v----declare the variable
    var link;
    if (!document.getElementById) {
        return false;
    }
    if (please_wait != null) {
          // ----------------------v---"target" is a String???
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = please_wait;
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        link = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        link = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (link == undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    link.onreadystatechange = function () {
        response(url, target, link); // <-- pass "link" to the response
    }
    link.open("GET", url, true);
    link.send(null);
}

  // receive "link"-------------v----so that you have the correct xhr object
function response(url, target, link) {
    if (link.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = (link.status == 200) ? link.responseText : "Ooops!! A broken link! Please contact the webmaster of this website  and give him the following errorcode: " + link.status;
    }
}
function set_loading_message(msg) {
    please_wait = Loding;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you have contention on the AJAX.

Here is how your code could look in jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link1").click(function() {
    $("#containerA').load("firstpage.php",function() {
      $("#containerB').load("secondpage.php");
    });
  });
});
</script>

<a id="link1" href="#">  Click Here </a>
```

Alternatively use a queue manager plugin for jQuery